# Die problem for rolling sided dice

Tags: statistics

How to approach this question.Can it be done with binomial distribution because listing the possible outcomes is a very long method.What the shortcut the approach this question?

Comment: What is your requirement? Do you want to know the distribution of $Z$?

Comment: I want to draw the probability mass function for that need to find the probabilities.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What are the values that $Z$ can take?

Comment: So the total ways is 6^3 which is 216.So each value has the probability of 1/6. So basically I did binomial distribution  for example 3c1(5/6)^2(1/6)^0.I DONT KNOW IF THIS IS THE RIGHT APPROACH

Comment: Z can take values from 1 to 6 as its a 6 sided die

Comment: Why do you use Binomial distribution? What is the meaning of binomial distribution? What is 'success' and 'failure' here?

Comment: Are those dice rolled consecutively? If yes, how do the other dice affect Z at all? If the dice are rolled at the same time, what do you mean with "first die rolled"? Do you by chance (I assume not native English speaker) mean Z is the smallest of the three values?

Comment: Binomial distribution means that there are two outcomes p and failure so if I know the probability of obtaining the first six sided die and the rest is anything I think I can find the probabilities like this.

Comment: If already you roll the first six sided die along with two others then what is the meaning of finding probability of obtaining it?

Comment: No Z does not mean the smallest values.It means the first die rolled is lets suppose 1 and the other dies could have any values.Yes I think consecutively

Comment: 1/6 is the probability for each outcome

Comment: Exactly. Now you are on the right track.

Comment: This is called a "uniform distribution"; one where all outcomes have the same robability of occurring

Comment: Thank you I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answers under comments the OP has made clear that the 3 dice are rolled cosecutively. In that case, the result $Z$ of the first rolled die is independent of the result of the other 2 dice (or other 999 dice if 1000 dice were rolled).

That means the probability distribution of $Z$ is the simple equiprobability distribution for the integer numbers 1 to 6:

$$P(Z=1)=P(Z=2)=P(Z=3)=P(Z=4)=P(Z=5)=P(Z=6)=\frac16$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be 1/216 as the it is rolled three times.

Comment: As I tried to make clear in my answer, it doesn't matter if you throw 3 dice or 1000. If you only care what the outcome of the first thrown dice is, the others dice *simply don't matter*. Why would they affect anything when they have no effect on $Z$? If you want to go the route of considering all $6^3$ outcomes of 3 dices, then you get 36 outcomes with $Z=1$: first die is 1, second die is 1, third die is 1; fiirst die is 1, second die is 1, third die is 2, ... first die is 1, second die is 6, third die is 6. This gives you $P(Z=1)=\frac{36}{243}=\frac16$.

Comment: ohh I see.I get it now

Comment: $6^3 \neq 243.$

Comment: Sorry, if course $6^3=216$. Doesn't change the desired equality to $\frac16$, and now it's to late to edit the comment. Thanks for pointing it out!